# Should requests using OAuth2 rely solely on the bearer token?

Tags: oauth2

I'm using OAuth2 to secure an API. This API will be used solely by a known website and some Cordova apps.

- The website will send always send a corresponding `referer` header.
- The Cordova app will always send an `x-requested-with` header.

I have two similar questions regarding this.

1. May (or should) these headers be used to verify a client identity when requesting an access token?
2. May (or should) these headers be used in addition to the granted access token to verify the client identity?